# How to configure AWS Api Gateway to make a request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to access AWS ApiGateway

file.py:

```
import requests_random_user_agent
import requests
...
gateway = ApiGateway(
  "https://some-site.com",
  access_key_id=settings.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  access_key_secret=settings.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  regions=[settings.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION],
)
gateway.start()
session = requests.Session()
session.mount("https://www.some-site.com", gateway)
response = session.get(url)
```

But I get the following error:

```
[2024-02-23 13:55:33,594: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] Starting API gateway in 1 regions.
[2024-02-23 13:55:33,633: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Invalid endpoint: https://apigateway..amazonaws.com
```

Any idea how to configure it?

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to do this through the SDK and not using `requests`?

Comment: Are you trying to configure API Gateway to let Client apps make requests?

Comment: @Corey requests lib block me the get request and I need to use AWS ApiGateway proxies

Comment: The endpoint URL `https://apigateway..amazonaws.com` is missing the region identifier e.g. us-east-1, so you likely haven't correctly supplied the AWS region. That said, what are you actually trying to do here? Which package are you using to resolve `ApiGateway `?

Comment: @jarmod `settings.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` has `us-east-1` value and others AWS services such as S3 works well.

Comment: Well, some dependency isn't creating a valid endpoint URL, unless that error message is wrong. What is `ApiGateway`?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/requests-ip-rotator